# $A$ is diagonalizable, if $A,B$ have then same eigenvalues, then $B$ is also diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

> Given $A_{n\times n},B_{n\times n} \in \mathbb R$ such that $A$ is diagonalizable then:
>
> 1. if $A,B$ have then same eigenvalues, then $B$ is also diagonalizable over $ \mathbb R$.
> 2. if $A,B$ have then same characteristic polynomial, then $B$ is also diagonalizable over $ \mathbb R$.

Those two state basically the same thing and I read that both of these are false, but how?

If both have the same eigenvalues, then why both of them don't have the same diagonal matrix $D$ such that $A= P^{-1} D P = B$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{bmatrix}
 1&1 \\ 
 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
 consider these two matrices.(Jordan Canonical form is the answer).

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your last question: because there are nontrivial Jordan canonical forms.

Comment: This is correct, but probably not useful for the OP if he's just beginning to learn linear algebra.

Comment: I was contrasting "correct" and "helpful" - I think an example like the one in @Anubhav.K 's answer provides more information for a beginner. But am upvoting your correct answer too.